# Cygwin move file from folder to folder on Desktop and open Dreamweaver

Tags: cygwin

I use Cygwin, and I write commands. On my Desktop I have two folders, named `folder1` and `folder2`. In `folder1` there is a text file. I want to move the text file to `folder2`. But when I use the `mv` command it doesn't work. I get an error message "no such file or directory".

My question is: how can I move file.txt from `folder1` to `folder2`?

My code is:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Maichel/Desktop/folder1
$ mv file.txt folder2/.
```

This also doesn't work:

```
 /cygdrive/c/Users/Maichel/Desktop/folder1
$ mv Desktop/file.txt Desktop/folder2/.
```

I have one question more: How can I open Dreamweaver in Cygwin? If I use `notepad file.txt` then the file is opened in notepad. How do I do this with Dreamweaver?

Comment: You have two questions in one. Please ask the second one in a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference your paths properly. If your directory hierarchy looks like this:

```
Desktop/
- folder1/
- folder2/
```

Then from inside `folder1`, you need to navigate up one directory with `..` to get to `Desktop`, then go back down into `folder2`:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Maichel/Desktop/folder1
$ mv file.txt ../folder2/
```

You can also use the absolute path:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Maichel/Desktop/folder1
$ mv file.txt /cygdrive/c/Users/Maichel/Desktop/folder2/
```